# Make changes to minified css in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am editing the non-minified CSS file (I cant find the minified one) and rebuilding the project and when I view the site my changes aren't applied. When I go into the Umbraco admin pages and view the settings / stylesheets I see this:

```
@import url(../Content/normalize.css);
@import url(primitives/primitives.min.css);

@import url(content-types/_content-types.css);
@import url(view-pages/_view-pages.css);
@import url(macro-partials/_macro-partials.css);

@import url(richtext-editor-overrides/richtext-editor-overrides.min.css);
@import url('RichText Editor Styles.css');

@import url(themes/themes.min.css);
```

The _view-pages.css file is importing the file I am editing.

Comment: There is not enought information here? Where are the css files located? Is it a css file you created or one which is built in to umbraco? Are you using umbraco in Visual Studio have you just deployed the site?

Comment: the non-minified files are in a directory called css/homepage-view-page/ . I am using it in VS 2013. It's a theme so I am editing the css files that its using.

Comment: There might not be a minified version then. how is the stylesheet being referenced in the html?

Comment: by .min when I inspect the element.

Comment: These are umbraco internal css files you shouldn't really be editing these, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm basically just trying to learn Umbraco, I was going to try to move the navigation to the top of the page. This is my first exposure to it.

Comment: Then watch some tutorials or something? You are currently in massively the wrong place, you should *never* normally need to edit the umbraco back office files.

Comment: Ok thanks fir the information. There are some out there but umbraco.tv is a paid service.

Comment: There's plenty of free stuff, give it a google. Get a free trial of pluralsight, etc.